# How can I restore what I have done in PowerShell?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, windows-10

I did this in PowerShell:

- Checked out current restrictions by typing `Get-ExecutionPolicy`
- Enable PowerShell by typing `Set-ExecutionPolicy remotesigned`

When I run `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` in PowerShell I get this:

```
        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine    RemoteSigned
```

When I run a project in Visual Studio the `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")` throws a exception:

> FileNotFoundException was unhandled by user code.

How do I solve this problem or can I just restore the changes that I have made in PowerShell?

Comment: I doubt that changing the execution policy would cause the error you're getting. Please provide more information.

Comment: Windows doesn't generally support `~` notation in paths, that seems the likely cause of the error message.  In PowerShell you can generally replace it with `$env:USERPROFILE`, or in other environments `%USERPROFILE%`

Comment: @Burt_Harris, I'm super noob When It Comes To powershell and should never have touched in there from the beginning, so can you explain how I replace it?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers You are probably right, but I run a project in Visual Studio and it worked, did what i did in powershell run the the project again, and then I got exceptionst, I have no more information to give or am i missing something here?

Comment: The default depends on which version of PowerShell you have, which you can check by the first line after typing `$PSVersionTable`.   https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847748.aspx explains what the defaults are.   At least with some versions, you can type `Set-ExecutionPolicy Default` to restore the default setting.   Note: `Set-ExecutionPolicy` needs to happen from a copy of PowerShell running as Administrator.